# Tomcat + Railo: Error to start

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion, railo

Today I run updates in Ubuntu 12.04. I have done a reboot of the server. But tomcat can no longer to boot.

These are the errors:

```
    /opt/railo/railo_ctl restart
 * Shutting down Railo: Jul 18, 2015 4:16:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Could not contact localhost:8005. Tomcat may not be running.
Jul 18, 2015 4:16:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina stopServer
SEVERE: Catalina.stop:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stopServer(Catalina.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.stopServer(Bootstrap.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:458)

Tomcat did not stop in time. PID file was not removed.
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . [FAIL]
 * The Tomcat/Railo process is not responding. Forcing shutdown...
 * Forcing Railo Shutdown: [DONE]
 * Starting Railo: . . . [DONE]
--------------------------------------------------------
It may take a few moments for Railo to start processing
CFML templates. This is normal.
--------------------------------------------------------
```

**netstat -nlp**

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8798/nginx
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3770/php-fpm.conf)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4401/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8798/nginx
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3763/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3601/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3763/named
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN      3763/named
tcp6       0      0 :::4949                 :::*                    LISTEN      3715/perl
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      3601/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      3763/named
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           3763/named
udp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                                3763/named
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     25       1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7233     4761/perl           /var/run/munin/fastcgi-graph.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     3150     2126/udevd          /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8319     4764/perl           /var/run/munin/fastcgi-html.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3987     3608/dbus-daemon    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6324     4851/python         /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5586     3663/acpid          /var/run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4597     4401/mysqld         /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

**catalina.out**

```
Jul 18, 2015 3:33:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Jul 18, 2015 3:33:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8888"]
Jul 18, 2015 3:33:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 18, 2015 3:33:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jul 18, 2015 3:33:19 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jul 18, 2015 3:33:19 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jul 18, 2015 3:33:19 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jul 18, 2015 3:33:19 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jul 18, 2015 3:33:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8888"]
Jul 18, 2015 3:33:19 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

---

**UPDATE:**
OMG... Some days ago, I added a new host in server.xml but forgot to create the directory of the new site on the server ... On the first restart of tomcat froze everything ... I lost the whole day to understand it .... -_-

Comment: What is the first exception/stacktrace that appears in catalina.out?

Comment: OMG... Some days ago, I added a new host in server.xml but forgot to create the directory of the new site on the server ... On the first restart of tomcat froze everything ... I lost the whole day to understand it .... -_-

Comment: You can add as an answer the details so other can benefit from this.